# Call function in .js file from html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to call a function declared in a `.js` file from the body of the HTML. I'm assuming the reason it won't work is because the `.js` file is called after the function has been called in the HTML body. Is there a way around this.

I've had a look at some answers here, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. My apologies if it's staring at me as a beginner I may not be using the correct terminology.

```
jqueryfunctions.js:

function someFunction() {
    // do.something;
}



index.html:

<html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryfunctions.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            someFunction();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the full/actual .js file `returnedMessage()` is the function I was reffering to as `someFunction()`.

The console error I'm getting is "`returnedMessage()` is not defined".

```
$(function(){
    var timer = null;
    function appendmessageBox() {
        $('body').append('<div id="messageBox" class="datamessagebox"> </div> ');
    }
    // just before body tag.
    appendmessageBox(); 

    // makes MessageBox Disappear on MouseOver
    $('#messageBox').on('mouseover click', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(300);
    });

    function returnedMessage(message) {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer); //cancel the previous timer.
            timer = null;
        }
        $( '#messageBox' ).css('display', 'inline-block');
        timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
            $( '#messageBox' ).fadeOut( 499 );
        }, 5000);
        $( '#messageBox' ).append('<msg>'+message+'<br /></msg>').fadeIn( 200 );
        $( '#messageBox > msg:last-of-type' ).delay(3000).fadeOut( 3000 );
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $( '#messageBox > msg:first-of-type' ).remove();
        }, 5999);
    }

            // This test message bellow works correctly.
            returnedMessage('hello world - test 1'); 


});
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? It is working...

Comment: What goes wrong? Yes you can do that; if you're having a problem you'll have to post the error(s) you're getting in order for anybody to help.

Comment: Are `jqueryfunctions.js` and `index.html` in the same directory level? Check in your inspector tool under the `Network` if your JS file has been successfully loaded.

Comment: @ivan they're not, but for the sake of this example I didn't include the /js/ directory. I can confirm they're working though

Comment: Ok your code is working fine alone, are you sure the file is loaded? Something like that: https://image.ibb.co/jQyHKk/network.png

Comment: @Ivan, thanks. I checked that again all are 200 code. I took the liberty of stripping our all the js and putting in my basic `function someFunction() {alert('Hello World');}`, then calling it at the end of the html with `<script> someFunction();</script>`. But It won't seem to work for me.

Comment: write `console.log('testing')` or `alert('testing')` in `jqueryfunctions.js` and tell me if you get the console.log/alert when you refresh your page

Comment: @Ivan hi, yes this works correctly. After much experimentation I figured out that If I declare the functions in the `.js` file but use `$( document ).ready(function() { });` within the HTML, I can get the items to work in the way I require. Originally, I had included all my functions within the `.js` file between `$(function () { });`, and then called `<script> someFunction();</script>` within the HTML but it would appear to me this was happening out of the order I needed it to.

Comment: @ivan I'd also originally thought that all `.js` contents needed to be inside `$(function () { });`. Evidentially, the fault is the beginner in me not completely understanding what I'm doing! Can I ask you for a steer as to w what keyword I should research to better understand this area ?

Comment: ...and I've just read `$(function () { });` is shorthand for `$( document ).ready(function() { });`. I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

you should define your function like so:

```
var someFunction = function() {

   // do something

}
```

Or like so

```
function someFunction() {

   // do something

}
```

But always use the `function` word. More information on [function definition in Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp).

---

### More about JS file import

Javascript code is inserted between `<script>` tags in an HTML file

```
<script>
  console.log("Hello World!");
</script>
```

You usually place those script tags inside the `<head>` tag. However it's recommended you put them **after** your `<body>`. This way you allow the DOM to load before you run your JS script. This is important for exemple when you want to select elements in the DOM. If you put the JS code before the actual HTML that creates this element, then JS will not find the element you would be looking for because it doesn't yet exist.

Now it's not really efficient to work with script in your HTML code so it's helpful to write JS in `.js` files and then import them in you HTML file like you would for a CSS file. Use the `<script>` to do so:

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

You can use multiple `<script>` tags to pull in multiple JS files. But you need to be careful of the order you write them. For instance you have a `functions.js` file that holds all your functions, and a `menu.js` that handles the menu on your application. You're using functions from the code `functions.js` in `menu.js` so you need to import the files in this order:

```
<script src="functions.js"></script>
<script src="menu.js"></script>
```

First declared, first loaded.

Comment: That's fine but it doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work, which is apparently should.

Comment: Thanks Iva, this was most helpful in finding the issue.

Comment: I'm happy i helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You can write own function like this:

Here you can see simple example: https://jsbin.com/munowupipo/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Define a Function in jQuery</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.myFunction = function() { 
        alert('You have successfully defined the function!'); 
    }
    $(".call-btn").click(function(){
        $.fn.myFunction();
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="call-btn">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take the function on document is ready, so you must to write:

```
<script>
$(document).on("ready", function() { yourfunction(); });
</script>
```